Firestore (10.12.5): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream
I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase database, and here is the data I had 
Here is the code in my firebase.ts
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = initializeFirestore(app, { experimentalForceLongPolling: true });
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { db, storage };

And the code in my Demo.tsx file
"use client";

import { db } from "@/firebase";
import { collection, orderBy, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useCollection } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";

function Demo() {
  const [messages, loading, error] = useCollection(
      query(
        collection(
          db,
          "resume",
        ),
        // orderBy("createdAt", "asc")
      )
  );

  console.log('resume', messages, loading, error)

  return (
    <div>
      hehe
    </div>
  )
}

export default Demo

I always get the issue in console. Can anyone know how to fix it, please?

